# How to make joudi/Laravel-H5P work to implement an editor for H5P files?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I've been trying to get [djoudi/Laravel-H5P](https://github.com/djoudi/Laravel-H5P) to work to implement an editor for [H5P](https://h5p.org/) contents without using any of their Drupal/Moodle/Wordpress plugins.

I'm basically stuck at a point described in [this issue](https://github.com/djoudi/Laravel-H5P/issues/12) (which is supposed to be solved) about incompatibility with `H5PFrameworkInterface`. Here's what I did:

1. `composer create-project laravel/laravel="5.5.*" my-project`
2. `composer require djoudi/laravel-h5p`
3. replace two pairs of `{}` with `[]` (probably depending on PHP version):

   - `/vendor/h5p/h5p-core/h5p.classes.php`, line 2747
   - `/vendor/h5p/h5p-core/h5p-development.class.php`, line 70
4. `php artisan vendor:publish`
5. `php artisan migrate`
6. add these lines to `autoload/classmap` in `composer.json`:

   ```
   "vendor/h5p/h5p-core/h5p-default-storage.class.php",
   "vendor/h5p/h5p-core/h5p-development.class.php",
   "vendor/h5p/h5p-core/h5p-event-base.class.php",
   "vendor/h5p/h5p-core/h5p-file-storage.interface.php",
   "vendor/h5p/h5p-core/h5p.classes.php",
   "vendor/h5p/h5p-editor/h5peditor-ajax.class.php",
   "vendor/h5p/h5p-editor/h5peditor-ajax.interface.php",
   "vendor/h5p/h5p-editor/h5peditor-file.class.php",
   "vendor/h5p/h5p-editor/h5peditor-storage.interface.php",
   "vendor/h5p/h5p-editor/h5peditor.class.php"
   ```
7. add this line to `providers` in `config/app.php`:  
   `Djoudi\LaravelH5p\LaravelH5pServiceProvider::class`
8. `php artisan make:auth`
9. do the following

   ```
   cd public
   mkdir vendor
   cd vendor
   mkdir h5p
   cd h5p
   ln -s ../../../storage/h5p/content
   ln -s ../../../storage/h5p/editor
   ln -s ../../../storage/h5p/libraries
   ```

I also tried specifying version 2.0 of the package in `composer.json` (which required using Laravel 5.8 instead). That seemed to work a little better from a technical perspective, but I didn't manage to install any libraries or create any H5P contents, either. Basically, any H5P library I upload seems to be recognised as a valid H5P file and extracting the zip file works, but no library is found/installed.

How can I make any combination of this project and Laravel work?

Comment: As a good hint: never edit anything in `vendor` - never. It won't survive any following calls of `composer install`

Comment: Additionally, what **exactly** is not working? Is there any error message you could share?

Comment: Thanks, I‘m aware about that, it‘s just that I‘m still in a phase of evaluation: As of now, I‘m not even sure what exactly this app is supposed to do when working. I didn‘t include an error message, but there‘s a link to the corresponding issue on GitHub in my question.

Comment: Hi,
I just install this package in fresh laravel project but i dont know how to run this library.
Can you please share a full demo project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be sure of make php configurations listed in https://h5p.org/installation/configure-php.
You need to have installed this extensions of PHP:

- ZipArchive (mandatory)
- mbstring (mandatory)
- openssl (optional)

In the file "C:\laragon\www\h5pintegration\vendor\djoudi\laravel-h5p\src\LaravelH5p\Storages\LaravelH5pStorage.php" the function "saveFileFromZip($path, $file, $stream)" should got this code:

```
/**
   * Store the given stream into the given file.
   *
   * @param string $path
   * @param string $file
   * @param resource $stream
   * @return bool
   */
  public function saveFileFromZip($path, $file, $stream){
    // Add filename to path
    $absolutePath = $path.'/'.$file;
    $newDirPath = preg_replace("/\/[^\/]+\/?$/", '', $absolutePath);
    if (!self::dirReady($newDirPath)) {
      throw new \Exception('unabletocopy');
    }

    if ($stream) {
      file_put_contents($absolutePath, $stream);
    }

    return true;
  }
```

(I should make a pull request, I dont know how yet)

When you have that you can see the package in action http://localhost/h5p

Now you can load libraries.

You can get the h5p libraries from https://h5p.org/content-types-and-applications

- select one and click
- when the example opens, click in "Reuse" (left-bottom corner of the conteiner)
- click in "Download as an .h5p file"

When you upload a content form a .h5p file, it loads all the depending libraries.

That's what I got so far...

I found https://github.com/exatech-group/Laravel-H5P its a fork of djoudi/Laravel-H5P 2.0 but its updated.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you very much and sorry for the late reply, I‘m traveling and was unaware I wouldn’t get notifications from SO on the device I‘m using. I‘ll probably work on this on Monday and give feedback.

Comment: I managed to upload a library using version 2 of Djoudi's package. However, I couldn't create a content. With the Exatech package, I can't add any libraries yet due to DB problems. However, I managed to create a content (after adding an authentification system using `php artisan make:auth`) using the same database (including the library I had just uploaded) I used with Djoudi's package. I guess there's still a lot of work to do before I manage to build a working H5P editor with any of these packages. The Exatech package appears to be a more promising starting point.

Comment: Hi, I just install this package in fresh laravel project but i dont know how to run this library. Can you please share a full demo project?

Answer (score 0):

If you need a working version of h5p laravel you can use EscolaLMS/H5P

There is demo deployed on the heroku you can play with <s>https://h5p-laravel-demo.herokuapp.com/</s> https://h5p-laravel-demo.stage.etd24.pl/

EDIT: https://h5p-laravel-demo.herokuapp.com/ no longer works

Comment: The link is not working.

Comment: https://h5p-laravel-demo.stage.etd24.pl/ is one link that works, there was to much effort to make heroku work with laravel

Answer (score 0):

h5p-laravel-demo.stage.etd24.pl  I am getting difficulty installing this one. I am unable to run artisan command

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34475894)